# Using Bash to Count Lines with text in a specifin range with a specifc word

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a CSV file with data like this (almost 100000 lines). I need to count how many times does a specific word with a specific date appears in the file for a range of dates. For example from 15/03/2020 to 16/04/2020 I need to count how many times the word "Sinaloa" appears which means count all "Sinaloa" with 15/03/2020, 16/03/2020, 17/03/2020, ... , 16/04/2020

I tried using grep but it only counts the first and last date.

Edit: Let's take "Ciudad de Mexico" and a date such as 25/04/2020. I need to count all the "Ciudad de Mexico" from 15/03/2020 to 25/04/2020. In this case the desire output is 5. But the problem is that the final date in this case is an input from the user, so it if changes to 01/05/2020  the output should be 6.

```
"167386","Baja California","F",54,"01/04/2020","confirmado"
"0d01b5","Sinaloa","F",60,"13/04/2020","confirmado"
"1beec8","Ciudad de México","M",47,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"15fcd7","Ciudad de México","M",46,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"0a5675","Sinaloa","F",34,"19/05/2020","confirmado"
"0e9e95","Ciudad de México","F",31,"25/04/2020","confirmado"
"07fa63","Ciudad de México","M",37,"01/05/2020","confirmado"
"0693ef","Ciudad de México","F",48,"20/03/2020","confirmado"
"19afc8","Baja California","F",45,"06/04/2020","confirmado"
"093740","Baja California","M",81,"19/04/2020","confirmado"
"1b3c74","México","M",57,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"025cb1","Baja California","M",51,"29/04/2020","confirmado"
"15764f","México","M",73,"05/05/2020","confirmado"
"07c084","Tabasco","F",52,"23/04/2020","confirmado"
"1b9e29","Ciudad de México","F",47,"11/04/2020","confirmado"
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice specific CSV parser, more user friendly than [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to parse real CSV, [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit)

You have 0 match:

### Input file

Added needed headers:

```
"c1",    "c2",             "c3","c4", "c5",     "c6"
"167386","Baja California","F",54,"01/04/2020","confirmado"
"0d01b5","Sinaloa","F",60,"13/04/2020","confirmado"
"1beec8","Ciudad de México","M",47,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"15fcd7","Ciudad de México","M",46,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"0a5675","Sinaloa","F",34,"19/05/2020","confirmado"
"0e9e95","Ciudad de México","F",31,"25/04/2020","confirmado"
"07fa63","Ciudad de México","M",37,"01/05/2020","confirmado"
"0693ef","Ciudad de México","F",48,"20/03/2020","confirmado"
"19afc8","Baja California","F",45,"06/04/2020","confirmado"
"093740","Baja California","M",81,"19/04/2020","confirmado"
"1b3c74","México","M",57,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"025cb1","Baja California","M",51,"29/04/2020","confirmado"
"15764f","México","M",73,"05/05/2020","confirmado"
"07c084","Tabasco","F",52,"23/04/2020","confirmado"
"1b9e29","Ciudad de México","F",47,"11/04/2020","confirmado"
```

Command:

```
$ csvgrep -c2 -r '^Sinaloa$' file | grep -c '1[567]/04/2020'
```

### Output

```
0
```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself properly. What I am doing is asking the user for a state and a date for example for the state the user types "Sinaloa" an for the date the user typer 15/06/2020. My initial date is 15/03/2020.So I need to count all the "Sinaloa" s all the 

Sinaloa 15/03/2020
Sinaloa 16/03/2020
Sinaloa 17/03/2020
Sinaloa 18/03/2020
   .
   .
   .
Sinaloa 31/03/2020
Sinaloa 01/04/2020 

Until the last one that is Sinaloa 16/06/2020

Comment: Thank you in advandce c:

Comment: This is unclear for me, please add expected output in your original post

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over dates and grep the pattern

```
d="2020-03-15"
until [[ "$d" == "2020-04-26" ]]; do 
    pattern=$(date -d "$d" +%d/%m/%Y)
    d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
    grep "Ciudad de México.*$pattern" file.csv
done
```

output

```
"0693ef","Ciudad de México","F",48,"20/03/2020","confirmado"
"1b9e29","Ciudad de México","F",47,"11/04/2020","confirmado"
"1beec8","Ciudad de México","M",47,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"15fcd7","Ciudad de México","M",46,"16/04/2020","confirmado"
"0e9e95","Ciudad de México","F",31,"25/04/2020","confirmado"
```

Comment: Thank you this has helped me a lot but when I try to run grep -c  It doesn't return the number of lines.  Any suggestion?

Comment: because in each iteration grep searches for one date, if you need the count of lines, you should sum them.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the variables to `awk`

```
awk -F\" -v city="Ciudad de México" -v from="01/04/2020" -v to="16/04/2020" '
  BEGIN{split(to,t,"/"); split(from,f,"/"); 
    to=mktime(t[3]" "t[2]" "t[1]" 0 0 0"); from=mktime(f[3]" "f[2]" "f[1]" 0 0 0")}
  $4~city{split($8,th,"/"); this=mktime(th[3]" "th[2]" "th[1]" 0 0 0");
    c+=(this<=to&&this>=from)}END{print city, c}' file

Ciudad de México 3
```

**Walkthrough**

Split on `"` and load the criteria

```
awk -F\" -v city="Ciudad de México" -v from="01/04/2020" -v to="16/04/2020" '
```

Grab the date elements from your datespec variables

```
  BEGIN{split(to,t,"/"); split(from,f,"/");
```

Convert them to timestamps

```
    to=mktime(t[3]" "t[2]" "t[1]" 0 0 0"); from=mktime(f[3]" "f[2]" "f[1]" 0 0 0")}
```

Loop over the main file checking for the `city` in `$4` and grab the timestamp from `$8` if there is a match

```
  $4~city{split($8,th,"/"); this=mktime(th[3]" "th[2]" "th[1]" 0 0 0");
```

Increment the counter `c` if the timestamp  is in range

```
    c+=(this<=to&&this>=from)}
```

....

```
  END{print city, c}' file
```